# Power BI Premium - You cant get here from there

Tags: powerbi

We have Power BI Premium and have created some reports for our Client and published a App.  The app can be viewed fine for our internal users and also for external users who are NOT on the Client network.

The issue seems to be that the Client has some sort of security policy that prevents them from accessing our PBI App, even though they have whitelisted the URL in the firewall.

The popup box says:  "You cant here from there"

Any ideas, I'm pulling my hair out on this one.

Pete..

Comment: Are your external users guest users in your AD, and do they use your tennat url to log into your power bi??

Comment: Hi Jon, we have user@ext.domain accounts for them in AD.  The whitelisting at their FW is for the PowerBI App, not the tenant URL.